# How to force Rails ActiveRecord to commit a transaction flush

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

Is it possible to force ActiveRecord to push/flush a transaction (or just a save/create)?

I have a clock worker that creates tasks in the background for several task workers.  The problem is, the clock worker will sometimes create a task and push it to a task worker before the clock worker information has been fully flushed to the db which causes an ugly race condition.

Using after_commit isn't really viable due to the architecture of the product and how the tasks are generated.

So in short, I need to be able to have one worker create a task and flush that task to the db.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ActiveRecord uses `#transaction` to create a block that begins and either rolls back or commits a transaction.  I believe that would help your issue.  Essentially (presuming Task is an ActiveRecord class):

```
Task.transaction do
  new_task = Task.create(...)
end

BackgroundQueue.enqueue(new_task)
```

You could also go directly to the `#connection` underneath with:

```
Task.connection.commit_db_transaction
```

That's a bit low-level, though, and you have to be pretty confident about the way the code is being used.  `#after_commit` is the best answer, even if it takes a little rejiggering of the code to make it work.  If it won't work for certain, then these two approaches should help.

Answer (score 0):

`execute` uses `async_exec` under the hood which may or may not be what you want. You could try using the lower level methods `execute_and_clear` (or even `exec_no_cache`) instead.