# How can I tell when an ActiveRecord::Base.transaction block commits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

A [common problem](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/FAQ#why-am-i-seeing-a-lot-of-cant-find-modelname-with-id12345-errors-with-sidekiq) with background jobs and ActiveRecord is when jobs get enqueued and executed *before* a needed model is committed to the database.

ActiveRecord models have a nice `after_commit` callback that can be used for a particular model.

But let's say you've got some business logic that touches a few different models, and it's not really appropriate to cram that logic inside a single model. So, you write some sort of service/command object that performs the logic inside a transaction block:

For example, something along the lines of:

```
class SomeServiceObject

  def execute
    thing = create_thing_in_a_tx

    # this notification often fires before the above transaction commits.
    notify_user(thing)
  end

  private

  def create_thing_in_a_tx
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      a = ModelA.new(foo: 'bar')
      b = ModelB.new(a_record: a, biz: 'baz')
      #... various other logic that doesn't really belong in a model ...
      ThingModel.create!(b_record: b)
    end
  end

  def notify_user(thing)
    EnqueueJob.process_asyc(thing.id)
  end
end
```

In this case, as far as I can tell, you don't really have access to the handy `after_commit` callback.

I suppose in the above example, you could have `ThingModel` enqueue the job inside of its `after_commit` callback, but then you're spreading what should be the responsibilities of `SomeServiceObject` across different classes, and that *feels* wrong.

Given all of the above, is there any reasonable way to know when a `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block commits, without resorting to any particular model's `after_commit` callback?

Thank you! :-D

(See also: [How to force Rails ActiveRecord to commit a transaction flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574997/how-to-force-rails-activerecord-to-commit-a-transaction-flush))

Answer (score 6):

It's simpler than you might think. After the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block completes, the transaction has been committed.

```
def create_thing_in_a_tx
  begin
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      a = ModelA.new(foo: 'bar')
      b = ModelB.new(a_record: a, biz: 'baz')
      #... various other logic that doesn't really belong in a model ...
      ThingModel.create!(b_record: b)
    end
    # The transaction COMMIT has happened.  Do your after commit logic here.
  rescue # any exception
    # The transaction was aborted with a ROLLBACK.  
    # Your after commit logic above won't be executed.
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, Bill! So, in the example code I posed, the `notify_user` method should only be called if the transaction has successfully committed, right? For some reason, that doesn't appear to be the case for me; `notify_user` *does* get called before the commit, leading to the job being enqueued before `thing` is available. Is it really guaranteed that the transaction has successfully committed when the block completes?

Comment: @JohnReilly, in theory, yes, but there are some cases that may be an exception.  Is there a wrapping transaction around the call to SomeServiceObject#execute?   Nested transactions are handled differently by ActiveRecord adapters for different databases; some database don't actually support nested transactions, they're all combined into a single transaction with checkpoints.  What database are you using?  It might be helpful if you could post your database/Rails logs.  You might also try adding (required_new: true) to the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` call, and test again.

Comment: @BillDoughty fwiw this did NOT end up being the case in my situation. We are running ancient rails 3.2 backed by PostgreSQL. I did some logging with timestamps both after the `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` block and inside of a `after_commit` callback in my model, and the former executed noticeably earlier. My use case required querying the created record in a separate service, triggered off of a Redis queue. I ultimately had to queue the event in the after_commit callback to fix a race condition.